# Analyse Soldiworks 2018 Files

Tags: mechanical-engineering

we currently need some help in analyzing the real (!) content of our design files of Solidworks 2018. Recently we are faced with ghost-parts within our assembly files. Unfortunately, support is not able to solve the issue by now. Since version 2015 the files are no more based on MS-CFB (Compound File Binary File Format). Does anyone have an idea how to explore the file contend? Greetings

Comment: I've never confronted with this problem, hope somebody else come to your rescue, if nobody will come up with any solution, try to ask in GrabCad, i know from experience the users there know much more about software failures.

Comment: ^I'd agree with the above. Re-post in a CAD specific forum!